Deploy to AWS using the Launch Template
I'm relatively new to AWS and just learning it with a little application I have built, but I'm having some challenges.
Here is my full story:
As we know, formally, we can deploy applications very easily using Elastic Beanstalk by just setting the application name and then configuring the environment, uploading our jar file, and everything is done.
But now that we have to use the launch template to define our environment and launch the EC2 instance, I became kind of confused.
Now, I have created a launch template and have used it to launch the EC2 instance, and I have also connected to the instance, but now I don't know how to upload my jar file to the EC2 already running instance.
I connected to my EC2 instance using the [Connect using EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint], and it's now running on the browser. Please, how can I upload my built jar file from my local system to my EC2?
Here is my EC2 running:

Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

System information as of Mon Dec 23 12:10:12 UTC 2024
System load:  0.0               Processes:             102
Usage of /:   26.9% of 7.57GB   Users logged in:
Memory usage: 22%               IPv4 address for eth0:
Swap usage:   0%

Ubuntu Pro delivers the most comprehensive open source security and
compliance features.
https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro


Expanded security maintenance for applications is not enabled.
47 updates can be applied immediately.
36 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
2 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
New release '24.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-146:~$
